# Is there another way to retrieve data from a web service without using JSON?

Tags: java, android, json, web-services, android-studio

I have tried to find another method to get data from web service and displaying it on an android app, but all of them just inform/ give the tutorial to use JSON.

Is there another way to get data without JSON?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use JSON?

For simple coding you can use Retrofit library.

```
http://mobilesiri.com/retrofit-tutorial-android-studio/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Volley instead.
Here a link on how to implement volley https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-volley--cms-23800